# How to remove published wmi schema?

Tags: wmi

I've published schema, and no longer have the dll's that contained the wmi provider that the schema was published from.  How can I remove the schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about the assembly from your other question, you can simply use wbemtest.exe:

- Connect to Root namespace
- Enum instances... button (Superclass
  name: __Namespace)
- Delete instance named Test or MyTest

That will delete the entire namespace including all the classes you created. If you want to delete a class and leave the namespace

- Connect to Root\Test
- Enum classes... button (Recursive)
- Delete the classes you want

If there are multiple machines this can be automated using WMI scripting library or System.Management. With MOF you can use #pragma deleteclass. If the schema was created with #pragma autorecover you need to remove the entry from

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WBEM\CIMOM\autorecover mofs